# Keycloak: user is automatically logged in after submitting the registration form

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak 7.0.1 and I have enabled the Resigtration link in the login page. My use case is the following:
Upon Registration a User should be created as disabled.
Admin user verifies the account then enables the user manually

The problem is that the user is automatically logged in after finishing registration. Any idea how to prevent this? (I also don’t need to enable any further steps e.g. verify email)

In keycloak mailing lists and also in the following post, it is said that automatic login is the default behavior, so is there anyway to change this?

[Keycloak automatic login after email confirmation with disabled user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382981/keycloak-automatic-login-after-email-confirmation-with-disabled-user)

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592742/registration-auto-login-disable/57603373#57603373)?

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem of automatic login. However, the user can direclty login. I hoped there is a way out of the box to create the user as disabled.

Comment: Also what if another login way e.g. Kerberos is used (no Username Password Form)? Is there a way to redirect to a page with a message like e.g. "Thank you, we will activate your account soon"?